# Obtaining and displaying file names using Shiny R

Tags: r, shiny

I want to create a Shiny app that I can quality control weather data with.  I want the user to be able to tell the app a directory with all the weather stations listed, and have the app list all the stations, so they can be chosen one by one.  To do this, I want to create a dropdown menu with all the stations listed, as determined from the file names in the directory.

I got most of the code from other answers (I admit that Shiny is turning out to be difficult for me!).  My question is how do I get the app to list the files (station id's)?

```
    ui <- fluidPage(
      sidebarLayout(
        sidebarPanel(
          shinyDirButton("dir", "Input directory", "Upload"),
          verbatimTextOutput("dir", placeholder = TRUE),
          
          selectInput("Station", "Select Station:",
                      datapath)
        ),
        
        mainPanel()
      )
    )
    
    server <- function(input, output){
      shinyDirChoose(
        input,
        'dir',
        roots = c(home = 'C:\\'),
        filetypes = c("csv")
      )
      
      dir <- reactive(input$dir)
      output$dir <- renderText({  
        parseDirPath(c(home = 'C:\\'), dir())
      })
      
      observeEvent(ignoreNULL = TRUE,
                   eventExpr = {
                     input$dir
                   },
                   handlerExpr = {
                     # if (!"path" %in% names(dir())) return()
                     home <- normalizePath("C:\\")
                     datapath <-
                       file.path(home, paste(unlist(dir()$path[-1]), collapse = .Platform$file.sep))
                   },
                   output$files <- list.files(datapath$files)
    })
    
    # Run the application
    shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

The lines I'm having trouble with are

```
output$files <- list.files(datapath$files)
```

and

```
selectInput("Station","Select Station:",datapath$files)
```

What is wrong with these?  I keep getting an error that says 'could not find function "path", and the server crashes.  Any help would be great.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure where `shinyDirChoose` etc. come from, as I don't think they're standard Shiny functions. Regardless, `output$files <- list.files(...)` is not going to work because it's not in a reactive environment. I think a better way of doing this is to render the dropdown menu dynamically (i.e., with `renderUI/uiOutput`). Since I'm not sure where `shinyDirButton` comes from, we can just do this with a simple dropdown menu.

Here's a reproducible example. I've commented out the code at the top; it creates three nested directories with blank files so we can test that the directory and file selector is working properly. We're just doing everything with `getwd()` to make this easily reproducible.

```
# create some test dirs
# lapply(c(1:3), function(x) {
#     dir.create(paste0(getwd(), '/', x))
#     lapply(c('a','b','c'), function(y) {
#         file.create(paste0(getwd(), '/', x, '/', x, y))
#     })  
# })

library(shiny)

ui <- {
    fluidPage(
        fluidRow(
            selectInput('dir_selector',
                label = 'Select directory',
                choices = list.files(getwd())),
            verbatimTextOutput('selected_dir'),
            uiOutput('file_selector')
        )
    )
}

server <- function(input, output, session) {
    # get selected directory from input
    output$selected_dir <- renderText(paste0('Selected directory: ', input$dir_selector))

    # render dropdown menu of files
    output$file_selector <- renderUI({
        files <- list.files(paste0(getwd(), '/', input$dir_selector))
        selectInput('file_selector',
            label = 'Select file',
            choices = files)
    })
 }

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: Thank you!  That works wonderfully!  The function shinyDirChoose is from the shinyFiles package.